# Use reactive stream/web flux with spring amqp application without web depedency

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-amqp, reactive-streams

I have started learning Spring web flux. My current requirement to use Spring web flux with AMQP in my project. This project is using rabbitmq Publish-Subscribe for AMQP messaging and project has no web dependency.This project will works in purely back-end side.

Below is my demo service file with rabbit-listener.This service gets required data in message payload and then service will process according to payload data and do the needful task.

```
public class HandlerService {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "${amqp.queue}")
    public void consumeMessageFromDlrRoute(final Message<?> message)
    {
        System.out.println(" message - "+message);
        try {

            ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream((byte[]) message.getPayload());
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(in);
            MyDomain domain = (MyDomain) is.readObject();

            // code changes related to this service.

        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

So for convert this project to webflux/rective streams with AMQP, I have referred this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-amqp-reactive and many more github projects. All sources are talking about to use Mono and Flux types with web dependency and getting required data from web/REST End points and then they manipulate it where as in my project, I am receiving data byte array in AMQP message payload.

You can find my current project demo on this - https://github.com/gotidhavalh/amqpdemo

So my question is that how can I convert this my project to use reactive stream/spring web-flux ?
Can anyone help on this.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is confusing. spring webflux **is a web framework**; perhaps you mean you just want to use `Mono`/`Flux` without WebFlux; in that case; see [Project Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) which is a dependency of WebFlux and defines those classes.

Comment: My question is that can I use spring web flux without web dependency in project but I understand that I can't use spring web flux in my case. Let me try with Project reactor. Thanks for this.

Comment: Again, webflux **is a web framework** it uses classes from project reactor.

Answer (score 2):

Project Reactor is a Reactive Streams implementation in Java.

To consume messages in a 'Reactive Streams' way, you can use [Rabbit Reactor](https://projectreactor.io/docs/rabbitmq/snapshot/reference/#api-guide-receiver) which is compatible with Project Reactor.

You can do something like this:

```
RabbitFlux.createReceiver() // default settings
        .consumeAutoAck("amqp.queue")
        .map(delivery -> new DTO(delivery.getBody())) // delivery.getBody() returns byte array
        .subscribe(dto -> {
            // do what you wanted to do.
        })
```